# Primes congruent to 1 modulo n

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I was wondering whether the following statement is true, and if so, how to prove it:

> for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exist prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $p\equiv1$ (mod $n$) and $q\equiv-1$ (mod $n$)

Feels like it should be true and that it should be fairly easy to prove, but I don't have any idea how. Could someone please shine some light on this for me?

Comment: [Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) tells us that there will in fact be infinitely many such primes.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a simple proof for the existence of at least 1?

Comment: There a relatively simple way to prove there are infinitely many $p$ using the cyclotomic polynomials, roughly like Euclid’s proof of infinitely name primes. I don’t know of any way for proving even one $q$ exists.

Comment: This answer shows the case of $p$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1160778/7933

Comment: Dirichlet proved that $an+b$ produces infinite many primes if and only if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, but this proof is not easy. This proof implies your statement.

Answer (score -1):

Comment: You can construct such primes; tank an arbitrary number like n= 7 we can have:

$p=2\times7-1=13$ ⇒ $p=13\equiv -1 \mod (2)$

$q=6\times 7+1=43$ ⇒ $q=43 \equiv 1 \mod 7$

In fact we must have:

$p=k\cdot n+1$

$q=t\cdot n-1$

From second relation we have:

$n=\frac{q+1}t$

Plugging this in first relation we get:

$p=\frac k t (q+1)+1=\frac kt q+\frac kt +1$

Let $\frac kt=a$ then:

$p=a q + a+1$

This equation has infinite solutions for p, q for certain value of a, among them primes for p and q. The condition is  $k>t ; t|k$.